# Display total of PurchasePrice column in a label on button click C#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, sum, label

I have a database with a number of tables.  One of the tables has a number of entries with a PurchasePrice column.  It is set as nvarchar.  I have a form that I want to display the total of that column in a label when a button is pressed.  I have tried a number of ways to do this and they didnt seem to get the job done.  Most likely because of the issue converting nvarchar to int.

Hoping someone can help me get this thing working.  Any ideas?

Comment: PurchasePRICE as a nvarchar? I would ask to do this conversion to the person responsible of this design.

Comment: Yeah that was me...chock that up to my inexperience...

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you(you need to set a reference to - `using System.Data.SqlTypes`):

```
SqlString s =new SqlString((string)reader["YourColumnName"]);
int i = int.Parse(s.Value);
```